# Getting string between two characters - Coldfusion

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I'm struggling a bit with ColdFusion (not the language I ever write in).

I am trying to do a regex to get a part of a string. 
So for example, if my string is: `D_CECILA23_CEC23423`
I want the part that is between the 2 underscores.

This is the code I have so far, and it works for anything that is alpha characters, but when a number is thrown into the mix, it just breaks.

```
<cfset myStr = "D_CELCI_LISA">
<cfset myStr2 = reReplace(myStr, "([\w\d\%]+)(\_)([/ A-Z]+)(\_)([\w\d\?]+)", "\3", "all")     >

<cfoutput>
myStr: #myStr#<br />
myStr2: #myStr2#<br />
</cfoutput>
```

Which gives me:

```
myStr: D_CELCI_LISA
myStr2: CELCI
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it really is as simple as getting the text between the first and second underscore character, you don't need a regex. This'll do it:

```
myStr2 = listGetAt(myStr, 2, "_");
```

That said, this should do for the regex in that context: `^.*_([^_]+)_.*$`, eg:

```
myStr2 = reReplace(myStr, "^.*_([^_]+)_.*$", "\1", "all");
```

Comment: That was magical. Thanks a mil. I can accept the answer in 7 mins.

Comment: Just a final question, say I would want the string after the last underscore how would I go about that ? example d_celci_cellu  and i want the cellu

Comment: listGetAt(myStr, "_") would be easiest. There's a bunch of list functions: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec1a60c-7ffc.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6a42 (where a "list" is any string with a given delimiter (defaults to a comma).

Comment: @user2429578 - Also, take a look at `getToken` (under string functions). It acts like `listGetAt`, except it does not throw an error if the list element does not exist.

Comment: Also consider just doing ListToArray

Comment: For Adam's comment I think he meant `listLast(myStr, "_")`

Answer (score 0):

@user2429578 ListLast() and ListFirst() for the last or first element of a list.